# How to find the most common elements of an array?

Tags: scala

How to write a function that takes an array of integers, and returns an array of integers. The return value should contain those integers which are most common in the input array.

```
List(5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4)  => List(5, 4)
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7)              => List(1)
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)                 => List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

I have already tried the following approach:

```
def mostFreq(info: List[List[String]]): (String, Int) = 
  info.flatten.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)
```

but it does not handle the ties.

Comment: When you say most common, is there a threshold value above which we can classify that en element is common ?

Comment: The element(s) that occur most times in the input it would seem. Why do you expect it to return `(String, Int)`?

Comment: You say it should return "an array of integers" but your code returns a single `(String,Int)` tuple. That's mildly confusing.

Comment: Sorry for confusion guys, yes the return should be an array, the above function is just a sample and this part is only important : groupBy(identity).mapValues(.size).maxBy(._2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can capture the max frequency similar to what you've come up with via `groupBy/mapValues/maxBy`, then apply `collect` to the frequency Map to obtain the list of elements with the max frequency, as shown below:

```
val list = List(5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4)

val freqMap = list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)

val maxFreq = freqMap.maxBy(_._2)._2

freqMap.collect{ case (elem, freq) if freq == maxFreq => elem }
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(5, 4)
```

Comment: I like this, probably cleaner than what I came up with: `info.flatten.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).groupBy(_._2).maxBy(_._1)._2.keys.toList`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341062/9297144)'s answer based on Scala `2.13` which allows us to additionally handle empty lists:

```
val list = List(5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4)
val freqMap = list.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_+_)
// HashMap(5 -> 3, 1 -> 2, 6 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 3)
val maxFreq = freqMap.maxByOption(_._2).map(_._2)
// Option[Int] = Some(3)
maxFreq.map(max => freqMap.collect { case (x, f) if f == max => x }).getOrElse(Nil)
// List(5, 4)
```

This:

- Creates a frequency map with `Scala 2.13`'s new [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]):

  - `group`s items (group part of **group**MapReduce)
  - `map`s each grouped value occurrence to 1 (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
  - `reduce`s values within a group of values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).
- Retrieves an optional maximum frequency using `Scala 2.13`'s new [`maxByOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.html#maxByOption[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Option[A]) in order to avoid an exception on empty input lists.
- And finally maps the optional max frequency in order to collect only items with the max frequency and otherwise return an empty list.